# Excel 2010, an if, else construction

Tags: excel

can someone help me with this in excel?
I have to several excel sheets of an excel file for students assessment. 
The first sheet contains the total marks calculated from the total marks of all courses which contain their names.
The other sheets contains their marks of each respective course which also contains their names.
I want a way to import their marks from each respective course to the first sheet using an excel formula. Their names on the other sheets are not arranged in the same manner as the first sheet.

if the a student's name cannot be found on a course sheet then it should display zero

Comment: Is there any identifier of sorts that ensure the two worksheets and datasets are related to one another? In other words, what links a student's individual marks on one worksheet to his total in the other worksheet? I appreciate that intuitively these are linked; the question is more whether there is anything that links them in the data if their names are not arranged in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how your workbook is set up. A vlookup would be best here.

Here is the syntax:

```
 =VLOOKUP(ItemToLookUp,CellsContainingItems,ColumnToPullInformationFrom,MatchType)

 ItemToLookup: This will be the cell containing a student's name.

 CellsContainingItems: This is a range on the other sheets containing the students' names and
 their marks, with their names in the first column of the range. If your students' names and
 marks were on a worksheet named "Math Marks" with the students' names in column A and the marks
 in column B, the syntax for this range would be 'Math Marks'!A:B. If your students' names were
 in column B and their marks were in column H, the syntax would be 'Math Marks'!B:H

 ColumnToPullInformationFrom: This is the column nhumber of the CellsContainingItems range that
 you want to get information from. For you, it is the column with the students' marks. If your 
 students' marks were in column A and their marks were in column B, the column number would be
 2. If your students' names were in column B and their marks were in column H, the column number 
 would be 7, because column H is the seventh column in the CellsContainingItems range.

 MatchType: This is either TRUE or FALSE. If you set this to TRUE, VLOOKUP will return
 information for an approximate match. If you set this to FALSE, it will only return information
 for an exact match. Since you probably won't have students with the same name, you should
 probably set this to FALSE.
```

Comment: The order of the names shouldn't matter, but yes, the names must be on the left side of the CellsContainingItems range. Good point. The only reason I didn't include it is because data is usually arranged from left to right, and this is not usually a problem.

Comment: Yes but I need to display zero for a student who does not have his in a course sheet

Comment: Use IFERROR.   The Syntax would be: "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(vlookupvariables),0)" without the quotes.     If VLOOKUP does not return anything because the name is not found, this will display a zero